# mongoid find by created_at with regex not working?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using `mongoid` with ruby 1.9.3. Collection has more than 10 million records.

```
c = Contact.where(created_at: "2012-02-10 08:49:05 UTC")
c.count
#=> 2
```

However when I use regular expressions no records are found:

```
c = Contact.where(created_at: "/.*2012-02-10.*/")
c.count
#=> 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Mongoid myself, but are you sure that it supports regex when querying with `where`? This should work though:

```
c = Contact.find(:all, :conditions => {:created_at => /^2012-02-10.*/})
```

Comment: `"/.*2012-02-10.*/"` would be a string search with MongoMapper and they're both probably just handing it off to the MongoDB connection so you're probably right.

Comment: Oops, this morning I didn't even notice that OP used a string instead of a regex literal. Silly me, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: A regex won't work with a time in MongoMapper, you have to use a half open interval instead. I suspect the same applies to Mongoid but I am not certain as I don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how Mongoid does this but the query you want to get down to MongoDB is something like this:

```
db.contact.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate('2012-02-10'),
        $lt:  ISODate('2012-02-11')
    }
})
```

Note that we start with `$gte` and end with `$lt` to get the half open interval `[2012-02-10, 2012-02-11)` and that's the same as truncating the full time to just the date part.

With MongoMapper I'd say this:

```
Concat.where(
    :created_at => {
        :$gte => Time.new(2012, 2, 10),
        :$lt  => Time.new(2012, 2, 11)
    }
)
```

Perhaps the same thing will work with Mongoid.

Also, this:

```
"/.*2012-02-10.*/"
```

is a string, you probably want `/.*2012-02-10.*/` to get a regex down to MongoDB. That won't work with MongoMapper so I suspect that you won't be able to use a regex for a time with Mongoid either; both of them probably just hand this sort of thing off to the lower level MongoDB connection layer. In any case, you almost never want to use a regex like that with MongoDB as it won't be able to use an index, you'd want to anchor it at the beginning, `/^2012-02-10/`, so that indexes could be used.

Comment: After index added to updated_at :                                   c = Contact.where(:updated_at.gte =>  "Time.parse('2012-02-10')")  Thanks mu :)